# ¿Como puedo mostrar distintos activites dependiendo del tipo de usuario, con android studio y firebase?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Tengo tres tipos de usuario, los cuales ya pueden crear una cuenta, como conductor, dueño o cliente.

Actualmente si los tres usuarios ingresan correo y contraseña ingresaran al mismo mainactivity, pero lo que quiero hacer es mostrar activity distinto dependiendo del tipo de usuario, pero no sé como obtener esta informacion para hacer dicha distincion.

```
login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = login_email.getText().toString();
            final String password = login_password.getText().toString();

            mauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener
                    (login_activity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                     if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                         Toast.makeText(login_activity.this, "L O G I N   E R R O R", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }else {

                         Intent intent = new Intent(login_activity.this, MainActivity.class );
                         startActivity(intent);
                         finish();
                         return;
                     }
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

> Asi es como cree los tipos de usuarios

[image: Firebase]

Comment: *«pero no sé como obtener esta informacion para hacer dicha distincion»* Nosotros tampoco sabemos, debes explicar cómo tienes organizados los datos, qué campo hay que leer para saber el tipo de usuario, etc. ¿Intentaste algo al respecto? ¿qué intentaste? ¿qué error da? ¿qué dificultad tienes? Por otra parte, debes decir a qué Activity debería ser redirigido cada usuario según el tipo  ¿?

Comment: mostranos como tenes organizada la base de datos y te damos una mano

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue, aclaro que es la primera vez que hago uso de firebase por lo que no se muy bien si esta es la mejor forma, también les agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Cómo lo conseguisté solucionar?, ¿validaste algo en el codigo de Android o es cosa de fireBase?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo quieres usar una combinación de Firebase Authentication y Firebase Realtime Database. Cuando creas un usuario con Firebase Authentication los mismos se listan en ese apartado en la consola de Firebase, lo que podrías hacer es modificar las reglas de Realtime Database para que los usuarios autenticados accedan con su identificador y escribir en la base de datos un fila asignando a ese usuario un tipo, luego al autenticarse el usuario deberías consultar a la base de datos el tipo de usuario asignado y navegar a la actividad correspondiente